# Netsuite quote form not showing all subsidiaries

Tags: netsuite

We recently are trying to implement Netsuite on my company, but after setting up all the Subsidiaries I encounter an issue that I'm not being able to resolve.

So here is the steps that I performed so far, I created a new Customer and on the "Subsidiaries" sub-list at the bottom of the form I added both subsidiaries to it.

After that I went to the Transaction -> Sales -> Create Prepare Quotation to start creating my quote.

First step on the quote is pick the newly created customer, right after that is choose from the "Subsidiary" drop-down list which one I want it to use, unfortunately only the main company is showing there.

Where this data for the Quote subsidiary drop-down list is coming from?
If I went to Setup -> Company -> Subsidiaries, I do have both entities showing there.

Anyway any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the subsidiary field in the quote (estimate) record is sourcing from the subsidiary which is set on the customer record level. This is why the subsidiary field is populated only upon selecting a customer for the quote.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you've opened a transaction and discover at that point that the subsidiary needs to be added (to the sub list on the customer record), you will need to make that change on the customer record, log out, clear your browser cache, and log back in for that subsidiary selection to be available on the transaction.  You can also use a different browser or machine.
If you have the appropriate subs added on the customer record before you open a transaction, you don't have to jump through the hoops.